Is there a meaningful option to compute something like an effect size for Granger Causality?
I am running Granger Causality (GC) analysis using statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests between several time-series pairs.
The time-series pairs used for GC analysis all have the same length of n = 720 data points, and they all use the same kind of measurement.
Consequently, I obtain the GC statistics for time-series A) vs. time-series B), for time-series B) against time-series C), and so on. These GC pairs yield different p-values, such as in the SSR-based chi squared test.
Here is my question and problem: I cannot use a lower p-value in one pair than in the other to infer that the effect of GC is higher (or stronger) in the first than in the second pair. This is because the p-value mainly accounts for the estimation precision, so that a weak relationship can still yield a low p-value.
But let us assume that one GC pair yields a p-value of 0.005, while another GC pair a p-value of 0.1 in the SSR-based chi squared test. Is there a way to further demonstrate that the GC effect is higher in the first than in the second case?
Without going into all the theoretical details of my analysis, in my case the "hierarchy of p-values" across the GC pairs or comparisons reflects what I would theoretically expect. This means GC pairs that should exhibit a high effect size also yield a lower p-value than GC pairs where I would expect a smaller effect size.
But I cannot use p-values to statistically support my theoretical inference, and this is my problem. Therefore, I am looking for an add-on or additional way to somehow make my point.
Edit: I decided to add further info to my question. My primary aim is to statistically (quantitatively) compare the effect of GC between two instances of GC, not within one GC pair (even though the latter might be necessary and allows for a between comparison). To further clarify what I mean: Imagine running GC between time-series A and time-series B, and another instance of GC between time-series C and time-series D.
The question I am asking is if the effect size of GC is higher in the first than in the second GC comparison.
As I now understand it, I can compare the RMSE of an unrestricted VAR with only one time-series against a VAR with two time-series. Then, I expect that RMSE to be higher in the unrestricted VAR.
Question: Would I then compare the difference between the unrestricted and the standard VAR RMSE values given my aim explained above? More precisely, I would compute the RMSE as just stated for time-series A without the predictor time-series B, and then with the predictor B. I can then compute the difference between both RMSE values.
Finally and most importantly, I can repeat the same procedure for time-series C and D. Again, I here obtain the difference of RMSE, and in the ideal case I would expect that the difference between the "difference RMSE" resulting from time-series A and B is lower or higher than the "difference RMSE" resulting from time-series C and D.
For example, I would expect that the "difference RMSE" for time-series A and B is way lower if their p-value for GC was lower than for time-series C and D, which, in turn, would exhibit a higher p-value for GC and accordingly a higher difference RMSE (between their restricted and standard VAR).
I hope this all does not sound too confusing.

Since Granger causality is basically a measure of whether the past of some variables help in predicting others, one "quantitative" option would be to compute by how much (RMSE or such) the Granger causing variables help reducing forecast errors

A question related to RMSE in my case of GC to understand your suggestion: to compute RMSE, I would use the "predicted" time-series as, say, y_true, and the "predictor" time-series as y_pred. More precisely, I would use the "predicted" and "predictor" time-series that are the outcome of my VAR model (and the outcome of the VAR model was used as input for GC). Would this be correct?

I am not sure I understand your procedure correctly. What I had in mind is that you build two (VAR-based) forecasting models, one with the predictor variable and one without the predictor variable and then examine the difference in root mean square forecasting error.

Thanks, I missunderstood you and I have to read more about this, since I didn't even know that one can run a VAR without a predictor. So I am confused now anyway. Let me nonetheless explain what I meant: first, I take the time-series that I want to predict. Second, I take the fitted values of the VAR (for the same time-series that should be predicted). Then, I take the RMSE between those two. As I understand it now, that wouldn't make any sense?

You are right that it would technically not be a VAR anymore, but a restricted VAR that one could then estimate more efficiently than with equation by equation OLS.
What you describe is how you would compute forecast errors and an RMSE based on these in general, if I understand correctly. What I basically had/have to add to this is that you would run two different forecasting models and compare their performance in terms of their RMSEs

You understood me correctly, and I understand you too now. A summary: My understanding is that both your and my approach works. However, your approach seems more sophisticated. My approach only allows to compare the RMSEs between the single instances for which I computed GC (eg. time-series A and time-series B vs. time-series C and time-series D). Using your approach, I obtain an RMSE for the restricted VAR and the standard VAR. Hence, a within (instead of between) comparison of RMSE values is now possible (eg. time-series A alone and A + B where B predicts A). Hope that makes sense.

Measurement units may matter here. Perhaps you want to compare differences in RMSE, but perhaps you want to compare relative differences in RMSE.

Thanks and true. But the measurement of each time-series is the same in my case, meaning that all time-series share the same unit or type of measurement.
